# Editing Custom Object Records in a dataTable

Tags: apex, visualforce, custom-object

Unable to edit a custom object in VF.

Here is my controller

```
public class dataTableCon {

List<Feedback__c> fb;
List<Feedback_Comment__c> fbc;
public List<Feedback__c> getAccounts() {
    if(fb== null) fb= [select Name, Description__c, Importance__c, Resolution__c,  Status__c, Owner.name from Feedback__c];
    return fb;
}

 public PageReference save()
{
  return null;
 }
 public PageReference cancel()
 {
  return null;
  }


 }
```

Here is my VF..

```
   <apex:dataTable value="{!accounts}" var="account" id="theTable" bgcolor="lightyellow" border="5">
      <apex:column >
             <apex:facet name="header">Description (editable)</apex:facet>
            <apex:inputtext value="{!account.Description__c}" size="100" id="PanelId"/>
     </apex:column>
     <apex:dataTable>
```

which has...

```
    <apex:inlineEditSupport event="onclick" showOnEdit="btnSave,btnCancel"  />
    <apex:commandButton value="Save" action="{!save}" id="btnSave"/>
    <apex:commandButton value="Cancel" action="{!cancel}" id="btnCancel" reRender="PanelId" />
```

I can edit on the Description__c field but when on page refresh loses then new contents.

Please suggest.

Thanks.

Comment: In your `Save()` method you have to `upsert` your `fb` list. Is this a mistake while posting or you really missing it?

Comment: I didn't do it. After I changed as public PageReference save()
{
upsert fb;
return null;
} Its working :) Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you bind controller(back-end) data with a visualforce page(client side) you need to maintain the relationship correctly wherever you want, so that your page showing the updated values and database will be updated with the correct values.
You have brought the data into client side correctly but sending back to the database is missing. Add following line into your `Save()` method.

```
upsert fb;
```

If you are having multiple fields where some are just controller variables(not from database), some are from different objects, it's always good to have a wrapper class and bind a list of wrapper instance into the client side.